# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message 'Error processing your

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

Create a twitter login with twitteroauth (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master/src) SDK

Here's my code that I am using

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


    require 'twitteroauth/autoload.php';
    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', getenv('http://istshrna.com/dokholtatbik.php'));


    echo "<meta charset='utf-8' />";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));

        $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);


        $access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
        $content = $access_token->oauth('account/verify_credentials');

        $data = array();
        if( !empty( $content->id )){
            $data['id'] = $content->id;
            $data['name'] = $content->name;
            $data['screen_name'] = $content->screen_name;
            $data['picture'] = $content->profile_image_url;
            try {
                $user_obj->twitter_login($data);
            }catch (Exception $e) {
                $error = $e->getMessage();
            }

        }else{
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            //header('Location: index.php');
        }



    }else{

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
        $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));

        $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

        $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));

        header("location: $url");



    }

    ?>
```

but i get this error message when callback

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message 
>       'Error processing your OAuth request: Invalid oauth_verifier parameter' 
>       in /xxxx1/xxxx2/public_html/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php:138 Stack trace: #0 
>       /xxxx1/xxxx2/public_html/dokholtatbik.php(30): Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth->oauth('oauth/access_to...', Array) #1
>        {main} thrown in /xxxx1/xxxx2/public_html/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php on line 138

......................................................................................

Comment: got the same issue. anyone can help?